# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaDat on a null object reference

Tags: android, file-manager

While I am sharing the image I got the below error with the fileProvider

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();    
uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.folders.manager", gadapter.getSelectedItemsFile().get(i)));
```

Error:

```
022-04-13 11:31:15.755 7064-7064/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.manager, PID: 7064
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core..parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at .ActionModeCallBack.onActionItemClicked(ActionModeCallBack.java:435)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onActionItemClicked(DecorView.java:2739)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:171)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2171)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
        atandroidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
    at com.manager.Action.onActionItemClicked(Action.java:435)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onActionItemClicked(DecorView.java:2739)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:171)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2171)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:141)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1197)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3190)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4166)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Please post complete stacktrace

Comment: Updated the stacktrace

Comment: Can you post your `provider` from the `AndroidManifest`?